# Obfuscate External API Calls C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a code in C++ that calls functions from external library. The function I called is *CreateProcess* like below.

```
CreateProcess(NULL,pProcessName,NULL,NULL,false,CREATE_SUSPENDED,
      NULL,NULL,&suStartUpInformation,&piProcessInformation)
```

Now when I compile the code and dissemble it, the assembly shows the plain text as *CreateProcess(args1, args2, ...)*. Is there any way to obfuscate or encrypt the function call to API so that if someone dissembles it then he won't ever know which functions are called.

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like somebody is building a trojan...

Comment: Or worse. Are you working for Siemens? :-)

Comment: you are right my frend. Its some kind of a AV bypass stuff. But not for harm but to test the protection level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any function that is imported by name will always have the name embedded into the binary (in the import descriptor thunk to be exact), the detailed parameter info is gotten from the pdbs as Steve mentioned (however analysing debuggers like ollydbg can deduce args, due to the symbol name being available). The only ways to avoid this is to either encrypt to IAT (using 3rd party packers/virtualizers/binary protection systems etc, like enigma) or use a custom version of `GetModuleHandle` (basically just a PEB spelunking tool) and `GetProcAddress` (a PE  spelunking tool this time), then by storing all the api calls you need as runtime encrypted strings, you can then call whatever you need without plain text giving you away (securerom does this, though it uses `GetProcAddress` directly, along with some binary obfuscation).

**Update:**

for compile-time 'obfuscated' strings, you can use something like this (really simple, but it should be portable, if you use C++0x, this is a lot easier):

```
#define c(x) char((x) - 1) //really simple, complexity is up to the coder
#define un(x) char((x) + 1)

typedef int (WINAPI* MSGBOX)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);
const int ORD_MASK = 0x10101010;    
const char szMessageBoxA[] = {c('M'),c('e'),c('s'),c('s'),c('a'),c('g'),c('e'),c('B'),c('o'),c('x'),c('A')};


FARPROC GetProcAddressEncrypted(HMODULE hModule, const char* szName, BOOL bOrd = FALSE)
{
    if(bOrd)
        return GetProcAddress(hModule,reinterpret_cast<const char*>(reinterpret_cast<int>(szName) ^ ORD_MASK)); //this requires that ordinals be stored as ordinal ^ ORD_MASK

    char szFunc[128] = {'\0'};
    for(int i = 0; *szName; i++)
        szFunc[i] = uc(*szName++);

    return GetProcAddress(hModule,szName);
}

MSGBOX pfMsgBox = static_cast<MSGBOX>(GetProcAddressEncrypted(GetHandleEncrypted(szUser32),szMessageBox));
```

Optionally you may want to use MSVC's [`EncodePointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432254%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to hide the values in the global function pointers (just remember to use `DecodePointer` when you call them).

*note: code is untested, as its just off the top of my head*

Comment: Ever heard of import by ordinal?  (Although it's still quite straightforward to find the actual function name, it won't exist in your file).

Comment: @ben: yes I have, but not very many widows APIs (or other APIs) export by ordinal, winsock and ole are some of the few do.

Comment: Thanks! Necrolis, Well I m not going to use any 3rd party tool. My question was simple that how you would have an obfuscate call to a dll and its function in c++ so that it wont be revealed in dissembler. I found an example by calling MessageBoxA function in User32.dll. The code is loading the dll but not calling the function properly. see the code below.

Comment: @Mudasir Khan: I'm not seeing any code, you might have hit a comment limit, so rather update your question with the example your having problems with

Comment: Thanks Necrolis. Please see in last. I have successfully obfuscate the CreateProcess call but in sample code below i have given the example of a MessageBox.

Comment: @Necrolis. yes i have seen that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might use dynamic linking. In Windows, use LoadLibrary, LoadLibraryEx, GetProcAddress. Now in you code, include some form in obfuscated form of name instead of the real lib/symbol names and unofuscate it at runtime.

You might want to use dynamic dispatch (function pointers) so that the function called cannot be deduced easily from the code.

You might delegate the work of calling this function to another thread (using some IPC mechanism).

But it's quite useless, using a debugger it will very simple to find that this function has been called. And it will be very simple to detect that a process has been created.

Comment: Thanks ysdx. You were very closed to the answer. I did it using LoadLibraryA & GetProcAddress that u have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Ok! here is the solution. Lets say I want to call "MessageBoxA" from "user32.dll". 
So here is how I will do it using *LoadLibraryA* & *GetProcAddress* .

```
//Ok here you can see.
//I am passing DLL name(user32.dll) and DLL function(MessageBoxA) as String
//So I can also perform Encrypt & Decrypt operation on Strings and obfuscate it. 
//Like i can encrypt the string "user32.dll" and at runtime decrypt it and pass it as 
//an argument to "LoadLibraryA" and same for the Function name "MessageBoxA".
//The code is compiled in DevC++ 4.9.9.2.

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void HelloWorld()
{
        char* szMessage = "Hello World!";
        char* szCaption = "Hello!";
        HMODULE hModule         = LoadLibraryA( "user32.dll" );
        FARPROC fFuncProc       = GetProcAddress( hModule, "MessageBoxA" );
        ( ( int ( WINAPI *)( HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT ) ) fFuncProc )( 0, szMessage, szCaption, 0 );
}
int main()
{
    HelloWorld();
}
```

Comment: It is very simple from a disassembler/decompiler to find that the function called is MessageboxA.