# Hide the exported functions from appearing in the executable binary file

Tags: debugging, binary, executable

I wrote a code to detect the face and generated the executable file, but when opening the executable using radare2 I found that the names of the functions call appear, the green sentences in the image below :
[image]

There is any way to hide the names of those calls or get the equivalent binary of them, to make it harder for anyone to understand what is that code doing.
thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### strip

The best way to achieve that is to use [`strip`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strip). It will discard the symbols from the binary.

You have tons of options where the most aggressive one is to use `-s` or `--strip-all` which will remove all symbol and reloc information.

```
Usage: strip <option(s)> in-file(s)
 Removes symbols and sections from files
 The options are:
  -I --input-target=<bfdname>      Assume input file is in format <bfdname>
  -O --output-target=<bfdname>     Create an output file in format <bfdname>
  -F --target=<bfdname>            Set both input and output format to <bfdname>
  -p --preserve-dates              Copy modified/access timestamps to the output
  -D --enable-deterministic-archives
                                   Produce deterministic output when stripping archives (default)
  -U --disable-deterministic-archives
                                   Disable -D behavior
  -R --remove-section=<name>       Also remove section <name> from the output
  -s --strip-all                   Remove all symbol and relocation information
  -g -S -d --strip-debug           Remove all debugging symbols & sections
     --strip-dwo                   Remove all DWO sections
     --strip-unneeded              Remove all symbols not needed by relocations
     --only-keep-debug             Strip everything but the debug information
  -N --strip-symbol=<name>         Do not copy symbol <name>
  -K --keep-symbol=<name>          Do not strip symbol <name>
     --keep-file-symbols           Do not strip file symbol(s)
  -w --wildcard                    Permit wildcard in symbol comparison
  -x --discard-all                 Remove all non-global symbols
  -X --discard-locals              Remove any compiler-generated symbols
  -v --verbose                     List all object files modified
  -V --version                     Display this program's version number
  -h --help                        Display this output
     --info                        List object formats & architectures supported
  -o <file>                        Place stripped output into <file>
```

### GCC

In case you are compiling your binary with GCC, you can use `gcc -s` to strip the symbol table.

### Other compilers

Most of the compilers out there has the feature of stripping symbols and debug information from the binary. Check the manual of the compiler you are using.

Comment: But also how to hide the built-in functions like ( printf ) it appears and that option didn't hide it .

Comment: That's a whole different approach, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642980/obfuscate-external-api-calls-c) answer for example (windows).